# I want a function to remove numbers higher than 5000 in a string

Tags: php, string

I have a string that contains unwanted numbers ( any number higher than 5000 )

I want a php function to remove any number higher than 5000.

thnx :)

Comment: Can you post an example of string you have, so we can see its format ? *(and what you want as result, ideally)*

Comment: Do you have any problems with your current approach? If so please mention them.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

PHP < 5.3:

```
preg_replace_callback('/\s*\d+\s*/', create_function('$a', 'return trim($a[0]) > 5000? " " : $a[0];'), $input);
```

PHP >= 5.3 (closure support):

```
preg_replace_callback('/\s*\d+\s*/', function ($a) {
    return trim($a[0]) > 5000? " " : $a[0];
}, $input);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
preg_replace('/\b0+((?!5000)[5-9]\d{3}|[1-9]\d{4,})(\.\d+)?/', '', $string);
```

Comment: This doesn't replace anything for me..

Comment: thanx Matt .. thanx for your help .. it's ok :)

soulmerge .. thanx for your help , but the code didn't work